# Is there a single word that means "to act in such a manner as to serve as a positive role model"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can replace the first half of the following sentence:

> Bill's work and ethics were so impressive that he _____ a generation of students.

The intent is something like "Bill X'd a generation of students."

*Inspired* is not quite right, as you can inspire somebody to give up, or to do a bad thing, and the intent here is exclusively positive.

Comment: ***Inspired***?

Comment: Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic.

Comment: Okay, so you want to cut short the sentence and use instead _"Bill X'd a generation of students."_?

Comment: In the context, "inspire" has the more narrow meaning.  No worries there.  However, if it still doesn't feel quite right to you, I can offer "Bill paved the way for a generation of students".  Sorry -- three words instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

**Inspired** should work fine in this context. — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inspire)

> *verb, with object* 1.1 Create (a feeling, especially a positive one) in a person
> *"The gearbox is tight, but positive and the steering inspires confidence."*
>
> 1.2 (inspire someone with) Animate someone with (a feeling)
> *"he inspired his students with a vision of freedom"*

Or, try **animated** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/animate#animate__2)

> *verb, with object* 1.1 Give inspiration, encouragement, or renewed vigour to
> *"she has animated the government with a sense of political direction"*